# How to drop columns from a dataframe based on levels in a factor?

Tags: r

I create a dataframe dd:

```
dd <- data.frame(a = factor(c(1,1,1,0,1,1)),
             b = factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1)),
             c = factor(c(0,0,0,0,1,1)),
             d = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,0)),
             e = factor(c(0,0,0,NA,0,0)))
```

which gives you this:

```
> dd
  a b c d    e
1 1 1 0 0    0
2 1 1 0 0    0
3 1 1 0 0    0
4 0 1 0 0 <NA>
5 1 1 1 0    0
6 1 1 1 0    0
```

And I want to create a second dataframe containing only those columns where there is more than one level per factor. I have tried this:

```
dd2 <- dd[, sapply(dd, function(col) length(unique(col))) > 1]
```

which gives this:

```
> dd2
  a c    e
1 1 0    0
2 1 0    0
3 1 0    0
4 0 0 <NA>
5 1 1    0
6 1 1    0
```

As you can see this has sort of worked but the issue is the missing data. To get what I want column e needs to be gotten rid of as well.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this or another way to do it?

Would be very grateful for any help.
Many thanks,
Nicki

Comment: so you want to exclude the entire `e` column or just the `NA`s in the `e` column?

Comment: I think you want the `nlevels` function rather than using `length(unique(col))`

Comment: Thanks all for the quick help and different suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more correct (and more efficient) here to use the `nlevels` function to count the number of levels of the factor, instead of trying to compute the number of unique values.

```
> dd[, sapply(dd, function(col) nlevels(col) > 1)]
  a c
1 1 0
2 1 0
3 1 0
4 0 0
5 1 1
6 1 1
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `Filter`.  We could check the variance (`var`) of each column.  If the var of a column is 0, it will be coerced to `FALSE` while all others will be `TRUE`.  As the columns in 'dd' are `factor`, we get the variance of the integer levels.

```
Filter(var, dd)
```

If there are `NA` values, we can use the argument `na.rm=TRUE` in `var`.

```
Filter(function(x) var(x, na.rm=TRUE), dd1)
```

But, in general, it may be better to go with `length(unique` route as this can also work on `character` columns.
Using the `length(unique(`, we keep the columns where the `length` of `unique` non-NA elements (`na.omit`) is greater than 1.

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))>1, dd)
```

Comment: Won't the `var` solution exclude columns that have more than one level but contains NA's?

Comment: @user295691 It is possible.  I haven't tested it that much.  I would say for a general case, the `length(unique(` is more preferable as this won't work with `character` class.

Comment: @user295691  For `NA` values, we can use `na.rm=TRUE` i.e. `Filter(function(x) var(x, na.rm=TRUE), dd1)`